# Even If I said it to float left, or rigth it stays in the other row

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have made a menu, navigation for my website but for some reason he keeps putting the "Credits" page to the second row, instead of making it in the same row as my Home page link because i did `float: rigth;` and `float: left;`.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>My Webpage</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheets/main.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="titlebackground">
            <h1 class="title"> My Webpage </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menuitem home"><p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p></div>
            <div class="menuitem contact"><p><a href="other_pages/contact.html">Contact</a></p></div>
            <div class="article">Hello</div>
            <div class="article">Hello2</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And CSS:

```
body{
    font-family: Arial;
}

.article {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.title{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin: 10px 540px 10px 540px;
    border: 8px outset red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.titlebackground{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image:url(../images/titlebackground.jpg);
    border: 8px groove red;
}

.menuitem{
    float: rigth;
}

.contact{
    margin: 10px 540px 10px 0px;
}

.home{
    margin: 10px 540px 10px 540px;
}

a:link{
    color:#FF0000;
    background-color:white;
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

a:hover{
    color:#FF0000;
    background-color:white;
    border: 5px outset red;
    background-image:url(../images/titlebackground.jpg)
}

a:active{
    color:#FF0000;
}

a:visited{
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `rigth` should be `right`:

```
.menuitem{
    float: right;
}
```

Second, try reducing the margins of your `.contact` and `.home` to something like 120px to see them on the same line:

```
.contact{
    margin: 10px 120px 10px 0px;
}

.home{
    margin: 10px 120px 10px 120px;
}
```

Finally, add `clear: right`to your `.article`:

```
.article {
    clear: right;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwmoeR